# How to Draw a Line (Line as link) between two nodes in TreeView using c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to Draw a Line between two nodes in Treeview Control.For Example

[image]

The above image shows the two treeview nodes **Image Source** and **CogPMAlignTool**.Now I want to Draw a Line between two nodes like below image(Here i am loading by double clicking image source, after that i am giving that image as input to the CogPMAlignTool tool).Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although most controls allow [ownerdrawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyfab68k.aspx), this does not help you much since ownerdrawing tends to ask you to draw individual items.

Instead, you need to [override the control's OnPaint() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce.aspx), and draw your lines over the top after the control has painted itself.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. This link might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4548/Generating-missing-Paint-event-for-TreeView-and-Li